# Amazon CloudFront - protect video with Signed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

**BACKGROUND:**

Amazon Cloudfront video delivery with S3 storage: I am using a custom 360-degree video player. The player simply links to MP4 videos. The videos are not streamed but just a direct link with progressive download.

**ISSUE TO SOLVE ---> Signed URL**

1) The videos should ONLY play back from my website and not from other websites. Otherwise someone will just hotlink to the videofiles, and I will have to pay for the Amazon traffic.

2) Where and how to insert CloudFront "Signed URL" policies?? Most tips suggest to use "Signed URL" that is connected to CloudFront. But I cannot put the puzzles together, too confusing as I am only a semi-advanced self-taught guy. So..:

2A --> where to insert the CloudFront policy? On S3 console?Or where?

2B --> what exactly to write, pls. provide a working example!

2C --> how to include one specific domain

3)I also suspect that protecting the file permissions in a S3 bucket is not enough, CloudFront may ignore that permission rule. Is that correct?

**GUIDANCE:**

If nothing works, I am looking for a paid, 1-hour Skype guidence session where we set up 1 video together with CloudFront Signed URL, using screensharing. All with step-by-step explanation, so I can repeat the process for the other videos myself. And the Skype session is affordable for a budget sensitive Kickstarter / Indiegogo project.

I appreciate any help, really do! Thanks!

Comment: Did you read through this article? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand where to insert the policies. It doesn't say, or I missed... (And to be honest, their documentation is way too difficult and confusing for a small startup, who only wants to set up a few secure videos.)

Comment: Do you know where to insert the policies?

Comment: Where are going to store the Videos?Also this videos contains demo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpdlVrliMf0

Comment: Yes, I watched that video but they don't say WHERE and HOW to insert the Signed URL policy.. they just simply skip that part saying "you can set that up if you want". (great..) Videos will be stored on Amazon S3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) The videos should ONLY play back from my website and not from other websites. Otherwise someone will just hotlink to the videofiles, and I will have to pay for the Amazon traffic.

Right, so your web site needs to be running on a platform that can dynamically generate the HTML pages that link to the videos.

> 2) Where and how to insert CloudFront "Signed URL" policies?? Most tips suggest to use "Signed URL" that is connected to CloudFront. But I cannot put the puzzles together, too confusing as I am only a semi-advanced self-taught guy. So..:

The policy is used to generate the signature, and it is included as part of the link you generate, if you use a [custom policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html)  ... it looks like `&Policy=...` followed by a base64 encoded version of the policy.

It's in the URL?!  Yes.  The signature makes the policy tamper-proof.  This is embedded in the signed URL that your code generates with each page load.  If you use a canned policy, then you don't save/send it anywhere.  You use it for signature calculation and then throw it away because CloudFront already knows what it contained, because it matches the request that's being made (else, it's invalid, so the request correctly fails).

> 2A --> where to insert the CloudFront policy? On S3 console?Or where?

Nowhere like that.  See above.

> 2B --> what exactly to write, pls. provide a working example!

There is a working example [in the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-linux-openssl.html).

Stack Overflow does not have a free code giveaway service.

> 2C --> how to include one specific domain

That's not exactly how this works. Securing content by domain is not securing content at all, because that can be forged.

Your web site provides signed links.  The links are valid because they were obtained from you.  They are only good for a few seconds -- long enough to start the download -- and then they expire... so even of somebody hotlinks to them, you don't care, because the link is already stale.  But that is why you generate them with each page load.

Alternately, serve your entire site through CloudFront, and then use CloudFront signed cookies to allow access to your restricted content by anyone logged in to your site.

> 3)I also suspect that protecting the file permissions in a S3 bucket is not enough, CloudFront may ignore that permission rule. Is that correct?

No, CloudFront has no privileged access to your bucket, unless you arrange it.  A CloudFront origin access identity gives it the necessary rights to access objects in your bucket.

Read [Serving Private Content through CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html).

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much for such a detailed insight.The picture is getting mush clearer. To be honest, the AWS documentation jumps into too much depth without explaining CLEARLY the logic. At least I now started to understand the mechanism.I hope this page will help other new AWS users.

Comment: However, what I don't understand why you can restrict access by domain on Amazon S3 but not on CloudFront. Here is a quote from S3 documentation, and to me it seems that S3 allows domain restriction quite easily. QUOTE ---> " To allow read access to these objects from your website, you can add a bucket policy that allows s3:GetObject permission with a condition, using the aws:referer key, that the get request must originate from specific webpages. " --- Is there a way to make this method work on CloudFront as well?

Comment: That is a primitive mechanism of access control.  It does not really secure your content against being downloaded, but does make primitive hotlinking tactics difficult.  It can be accomplished in CloudFront for using [Web Application Firewall](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) or, if the content is public on S3 and no CloudFront authentication is used, by enabling this in S3 and configuring the bucket as a "custom" (not "S3") origin, and whitelisting the `Referer` header in the CloudFront distribution's cache behavior settings.

Comment: Thank you! I just posted the same question a few seconds ago on the main wall, but in the meantime you already answered here. But I guess it just helps the community.

Comment: I haven't seen it yet but when I do, I'll consider posting a proper answer or checking for one that already exists and closing it as a duplicate -- I suspect it's been asked before, so please remember to search before posting, because if you don't, then we have to. :/  The idea is that SO is a reference site, not a forum, and many questions already have answers.  Questions, as well as answers, should be useful for future guests, and comments and their content are ephemeral -- ideally they're for limited discussion that prompts edits to questions and/or answers that improve their usefulness.